# What's the best way to preserve dry dog/cat food for long run?

Tags: cats, dogs, diet

I buy dry dog and cat food (kibble) in large bags to save money.

What's the best way to preserve it? Deep freeze it?

Comment: Related: [How long is dry cat food good for?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/2728/how-long-is-dry-cat-food-good-for)

Comment: how long do you take to run through a bag?

Comment: I just bought a huge bag for my cat - 16kg, will probably take like half a year to finish it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I do similar with the kibble for my cats and I use airtight "tupperware"-style tubs to store it in.

I don't know how large a bag we are talking here or how long that might last you but I've never had any problems with mine.

While there shouldn't be any problem with freezing dry food I don't think it's necessary - generally keeping it in a cool (<100F) dry place and avoiding exposure to the air, large temperature fluctuations and moisture is the key thing.

Comment: I am not sure that long term freezing of dry food is good idea.  Home freezers do things to the moisture of foods.  Can you find a reference that talks about the harm or benefit of this?  If it is ok, Is a sealed container required?